# How can I create, access and remove elements in a vector (STL) of objects dinamically in c++?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, heap-memory

I am learning to code C++ right now and I've been struggling to finish this task for a few days as I couldn't find good examples online: basically, I have to create an entity called Students and all its attributes such as name, code and cardnumber must be created, accessed and removed dinamically. So, here's what I've tried, just to test some features:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class Students{
    public:
        Students (int codigo_, string nome_, string cpf_){
            codigo = codigo_;
            nome = nome_;
            cpf = cpf_;
        }
        void print(){
            cout << codigo << " " << nome << " " << cpf;
        }
    private:
        int codigo;
        string nome;
        string cpf;
};
int main () {
    vector < Students* > students;
    students.push_back(new Students(123, "asdf", "012.123-12"));
    for (int i =0; i<1; i++) students[0].print();
    return 0;
}
```

But it gives an error:

**request for member ‘print’ in ‘* alunos.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] >(0ul)’, which is of pointer type ‘Alunos*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
     alunos[0]->print();**

**How should I access, let's say, for an example, a third student element in the vector, then?**

Also, at first I wanted to use an iterator, but it gave a huge error and I couldn't seem to work with it, I had replaced the for loop line with the following line:

```
for (vector<Students>::iterator it = students.begin() ; it != students.end() ; it++) 
     cout << " " << it.print();
```

**Why I can't use iterators like this?**

I would really appreciate if you could also point some concise materials and textbooks online with more examples on c++ classes and object oriented codes, I keep finding recommendations on books with thousands of pages, which are not very practical.

Comment: Why are you using `vector<Students*> students;` and not `vector<Students> students;`?  Drop the pointer usage and your code will work.

Comment: The error message is actually pretty clear, and even goes so far as to suggest what you need to do to fix the code. Though Paul's suggestion is even better.

Comment: students[0] is Students* not Students. you declared students as vector<Students*>. so you should use students[0]->print().

Comment: Thanks, Junhee Shin!!

Comment: @PaulMckenzie, is the following code storing students objects in heap memory?


    vector < Students > students;

    students.push_back(Students{ 123, "asdf", "012.123-12" });

    for (int i =0; i<1; i++) students[0].print();

Answer (score 0):

> How should I access, let's say, for an example, a third student element in the vector, then?

Since your `students` hold objects type of `Students*` you need `->` operator, as follows:

```
for (int i =0; i<1; i++) students[0]->print();
```

Or just use `std::vector<Students>` instead like @PaulMcKenzie stated:

```
vector < Students > students;
students.push_back(Students{ 123, "asdf", "012.123-12" });
for (int i =0; i<1; i++) students[0].print();
```

So you won't have to deal with any pointer type.

> I would really appreciate if you could also point some concise materials and textbooks online with more examples on c++ classes and object oriented codes, I keep finding recommendations on books with thousands of pages, which are not very practical.

That question is *too broad* and the answer will be *primarily opinion-based*.

So I'll skip this part but I'm sure you can find some good books out by searching through the sea of the internet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want using pointer:

```
vector < Students* > students;
students.push_back(new Students(123, "asdf", "012.123-12"));
for (int i =0; i<1; i++) students[0]->print();
```

Or just normal type:

```
vector < Students> students;
students.push_back(Students(123, "asdf", "012.123-12"));
for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) students[0].print();
```

With iterator:

```
vector < Students> students;
students.push_back(Students(123, "asdf", "012.123-12"));
for(vector<Students>::iterator it = students.begin(); it != students.end(); it++)
    it->print();
```

Or:

```
vector < Students *> students;
students.push_back(new Students(123, "asdf", "012.123-12"));
for(auto it : students)
{
    it->print();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if I wanted to set this student.push_back() as a class method, let's say insertStudent() that inserts student in a vector like this push_back(), so how should I implement it? I mean, I can't call a class method unless there is an object, right? But, in dynamic alocation, the object would only be created in the heap-memory after we call this insertStudent() method, so there wouldn't be any object to call first. So how should I implement a insertStudent() method?

Comment: @Benuck The `vector` has an `insert()` method.  I think you should [read the documentation on std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, yes it does, but I wanted a method in Student class to insert a student object in heap-memory into a vector. How should I implement it?